# Cannot Use Time.Sleep In Python

Tags: python-3.x, windows-vista

I'm trying to make a login for a text-based OS in Python

I have tried to import `time` and `time.sleep` but it still doesn't work.

```
import time
usrname = str(input("What Is Your Username? "))
age = str(input("What Is You Age"))
print("Welcome",usrname)

if age <= 1:
    print ("That`s An Invalid Age!")
    time.sleep(3)
```

I don't see any errors because it's so fast it closes in 1/2 a second.

Comment: Additionally you mentioned not seeing any errors because it closes too fast. I assume you are double clicking on the program file in file explorer right? If you open a command prompt (cmd.exe in run or windows start menu) and change into the directory with your program in it you should be able to run `python file_name` and the output will stay on screen, even without the sleep. You might have to use `python3 file_name` if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `if age <= 1:` is never going to be triggered, because `age` is a string. As a result, the `time.sleep()` statement within the `if` block is never going to run.

In order for the conditional to work, you need to make `age` an int (perhaps by doing `if int(age) <= 1:`).

Comment: Also, `input()` always returns a string making `str(input())` unnecessary.

Comment: But `int(input())` could be used instead so that age would be an integer throughout the program (without having to cast it whenever you want to use it)